# Is there any implementation of decompressing/unzip/untar any type of tarball(zip, gzip,bzip2) file into a directory in Linux KERNEL?

Tags: linux, kernel, extract, implementation, unzip

Is there any implementation of decompressing/unzip/untar any type of tarball(zip, gzip,bzip2) file into a directory in Linux KERNEL?

I'm trying to decompress/unzip/extract a zip/tar file into a directory tree. I wonder if there already is some implementation there ?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be looking for the `-j`, `-z`, `-Z` options for `tar`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like that in the kernel.

The collective wisdom of kernel hackers is to never read (or write) files from the kernel itself. There's a variety of reasons:

- it puts policy in the kernel where it doesn't belong
- it's risky, because parsing files correctly (i.e. so you can't possibly crash) is *hard*
- it's hard: even relatively simple things, like finding out where the file is become tricky in the face of things like chroot and namespaces.

Note that there are implementations of decompression algorithms (gzip, lzma, ...) because the kernel itself can be compressed and must be able to decompress itself during startup.

It'd be easier to suggest alternatives if we knew what you're trying to accomplish.